# PHP A simpler way to calculate time until midnight?

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a simpler way to calculate the time left in a day than this?

```
$midnight = clone $endDate;
$midnight->setTime(24,0);
$dayLeft = $endDate->diff($midnight);
```

I was hoping for a one line solution using DateTime and 'midnight'. Using midnight tomorrow doesn't work as I need midnight relative to $endDate set as a DateTime.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of hours untill midnight with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095566/how-to-get-the-number-of-hours-untill-midnight-with-php)

Comment: I need the day left of $endDate.  Tomorrow doesn't work.

Comment: PHP7 allows you to do this as a one-liner with the `clone`: `$dayLeft = $endDate->diff((clone $endDate)->setTime(0,0));`... otherwise, how are you setting `$endDate`?

Comment: But a one-liner isn't always simpler, it's often (as in this case) less readable

Comment: $endDate is set as a DateTime.  PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: I meant, how do you create `$endDate`? If it's using a `new`, then you can recreate your midnight using the same method into a 1-liner

Comment: You already have a simple code. Remember, it's far easier to optimize correct code than to correct optimized one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
$secsTillMidnight = strtotime('next day 0:0')-time();
```

where

- `time()` gives the current time in seconds since jan, 1 1970 (aka "Unix-time")
- `strtotime()` converts a string to Unix-time.